# Why button name is not getting displayed properly in android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to display a button in following composable function. I have positioned the button correctly but it has text "Go to studies" It doesn't get displayed properly, like only little Text part gets displayed. Following is my code

```
@Composable
fun OnBoardingScreen6(navController: NavController) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(26.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
    ) {
        // Back icon at the top-left corner
        IconButton(
            onClick = {
                navController.popBackStack()
            },
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp, top = 8.dp)
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                contentDescription = null,
                tint = Color(0xFF039be5)
            )
        }

        // Spacer between IconButton and Row
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(60.dp)
                .background(color = Color(0xFF008746))
                .padding(horizontal = 0.dp)
        ) {
            // Outer Row content

            Row(
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(360.dp)
                    .height(64.dp)
                    .padding(start = 16.dp, top = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp)
                    .background(
                        color = Color(0xFF008746),
                    )
            ) {
                // Inner Row content
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.check),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(24.dp)
                )

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp)) // Add spacing between images

                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.close),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(24.dp)

                )
            }
        }

        // Spacer between Row and Texts
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .padding(start = 5.dp)
            .width(290.dp)
            .height(40.dp)) {
              Text(text = "All set",
                  style = TextStyle(
                      fontSize = 32.sp,
                      lineHeight = 40.sp,
                      fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                      fontWeight = FontWeight(700),
                      color = Color(0xFF000000),
                  ))
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .width(308.dp)
            .height(106.dp)) {
            Text(
                text = "You may now enroll in studies.\n \nThank you for your interest in Mayo Clinic research! ",
                        style = TextStyle(
                        fontSize = 20.sp,
                lineHeight = 28.sp,
                fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                fontWeight = FontWeight(700),
                color = Color(0xFF000000),
            )
            )
        }
        // Spacer to push the button to the bottom
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(0.dp, Alignment.CenterVertically),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
            // Button centered at the bottom
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    navController.navigate(Destinations.OnBoardingScreen5)
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(339.dp)
                    .height(48.dp)
                    .background(color = Color(0xFF0057B8), shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 24.dp))
                    .padding(start = 24.dp, top = 12.dp, end = 24.dp, bottom = 12.dp)
                ,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(percent = 50),
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xFF0057B8))
            ) {
                Text(text = "Go to studies", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, style =
                TextStyle(Color.White))
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I have tried to chnage the Fonstyle to Normal and also add Color for the text in a different way but the text doesn't get displayed properly, only little part of one or two characters in the word are getting displayed. Do I need to chnage to Box frrom Column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to just remove the `height(48.dp)` from the `modifier` of that particular button.

And, The code you have written is very complex and unnecessary. You can opitimize it completely by using some simple approaches like:

1. No need to wrap a simple composable in container like you have wrapped a single `Button` in `Column` you can just have that `Button` with the required properties.
2. In some cases you can avoid `Spacer` and use `verticalArrangement` instead.
3. You should not make height and width of composable constants and due to this your UI will not be properly align and responsive.
4. Explore theme so that you don't need to write same style for different composables again and again.

There can be many more improvements, but you can see the coding style from other good sources and try writing the code and then eventually you will get better results after practicing. After optimization you will be able to read and change the same code more efficiently.

Comment: I am just short with deadline so giving the client what it wants and also using the Figma measurments , using Column where it's told to use Column...But thank you for your suggestion, I would do it in my personal stuff first and then apply here

Comment: @TejasKhartude Although if you follow these tricks then it will also save you time to develop and the UI and code will be even better and eventually it will help you with the client.

Comment: @TejasKhartude Have the solution solved your problem ?

Comment: Yes, it is solved, thank you. Actually I am doing 3 developer's work right now because one developer left the company and other my Tech lead is having some issue with Android studio so I am just concentrating on work accomplished , haha

Answer (score 0):

That is because of the padding in your code:

```
.padding(start = 24.dp, top = 12.dp, end = 24.dp, bottom = 12.dp)
```

this just cuts the top and bottom of the view

Comment: So, I have to remove this line of code?

Comment: Yes, it's getting displayed now. Thank you