# Why is my Text not getting shown properly along with padding start of 27dp in android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am displaying a Text Composable that has content that says "Introducing" but at the moment only "Introduc" is getting displayed. And when I add padding (start=27.dp) it doesn't show even that. Below is my code.

```
@Composable
fun LandingPage(navController: NavController){
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start, // Align content to the start
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {

        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.mayo1),
            contentDescription = "Mayo Icon",
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(90.dp)
                .height(95.dp)
                .padding(16.dp)
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .width(101.dp)
            .height(28.dp)) {
            Text(
                text = "Introducing",
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 20.sp,
                    lineHeight = 28.sp,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight(700),
                    color = Color(0xFFC559C0),
                )
            )
        }
        Text(
            text = "Your Mayo Clinic",
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            color = Color.Black,
            fontSize = 40.sp,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 6.dp, bottom = 4.dp)
        )

        Text(
            text = "Research App",
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            color = Color.Black,
            fontSize = 40.sp,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 6.dp)
        )


        Text(
            text = "Participate in research studies to advance clinical discoveries",
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            color = Color.Black,
            fontSize = 24.sp,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 6.dp)
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(100.dp))

        Button(
            onClick = {
                navController.navigate(Destinations.OnBoardingScreen1) },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(60.dp),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(percent = 50),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xFF039be5))
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Get Started",
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                style = TextStyle(Color.White)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

So, I want to know where I am going wrong as when I had a diffrent font, it used to display properly but now it isn't displaying properly.

Comment: The parent Row has 101.dp width.. So its child cant get more than 101.dp of width.. instead of 101.dp, Remove the width from Row or try some thing like fillMaxWidth() on Row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.wrapContentWidth()` or `.fillMaxWidth()` instead of fixed with for the `Row` that wraps the `Text` composable. It will allow text to get the needed space in the row.

And again you can follow the optimization which I have mentioned in answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77014903/14972910