# Why are few words from my Text content not getting shown ,correctly or not displaying in android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have two Texts here 1) "Your Mayo Clinic Research App", here "Research App" should be displayed on next line. And, it does get displayed on second line but the "pp" from the word "App" only get displayed partially.2) There is another text with content "Join a clinical research study. Help transform the future of medicine." , here the sentence from "transform..." is below the first text part of the sentence but the the line doesn't display the word "medicine" at all. below is my code

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.mayoclinic.ecg_frontend_android.R
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.ButtonDefaults
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.Font
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import com.mayoclinic.ecg_frontend_android.constants.Destinations


@Composable
fun LandingPage(navController: NavController){
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start, // Align content to the start
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {

        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.mayo1),
            contentDescription = "Mayo Icon",
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(90.dp)
                .height(95.dp)
                .padding(16.dp)
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(28.dp)
            .padding(horizontal = 10.dp)) {
            Text(
                text = "Introducing",
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 20.sp,
                    lineHeight = 28.sp,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight(700),
                    color = Color(0xFFC559C0),
                )
            )
        }
        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .width(348.dp)
            .height(100.dp)) {
            Text(
                text = "Your Mayo Clinic Research App",

                // mc-serif/display-small
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 40.sp,
                    lineHeight = 44.sp,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight(700),
                    color = Color(0xFF000000),
                ),
                modifier = Modifier.width(348.dp)
                    .height(88.dp)
            )
        }
        Spacer(modifier =Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .width(320.dp)
            .height(60.dp)) {
            Text(
                text = "Join a clinical research study. Help transform the future of medicine.",

                // mc-serif/headline-small
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 20.sp,
                    lineHeight = 28.sp,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight(700),
                    color = Color(0xFF000000),
                )
            )
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(100.dp))

        Button(
            onClick = {
                navController.navigate(Destinations.OnBoardingScreen1) },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(60.dp),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(percent = 50),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color(0xFF039be5))
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Get Started",
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                style = TextStyle(Color.White)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not restrict the height of `Text` composable intead you can use `.wrapContentHeight()`.

And you should follow some practices I have mentioned here at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77014903/14972910

Comment: Yesm thank you it's working for displaying the word "App" properly but when i put the same code of .wrapContentHeight() , it's still not showing "medicine" word from the second text.

Comment: @TejasKhartude For second text you should unrestrict the height of `Row` by using `.wrapContentHeight()` for the `Row`.

Comment: Okay, so are you saying I should put .warpContentHeight() for Row only and not for the Texts inside it or, you are saying I should give .wrapContentHeight() to Row and First Text and not the 2nd text?

Comment: @TejasKhartude For the first text you are restricting both `Row` and `Text` but for the second you are restricting only `Row` so what I am saying is you should not restrict the height of composable otherwise they might no be shown properly.

Comment: I did upvote, my account is new so it's saying you are required 15 reputations

Comment: @TejasKhartude Yes, you are new to this platform that's why I am trying to make you aware of best practices. You will get reputation by doing these mentioned things at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation